# visual studio code is stuck

Tags: python, visual-studio, plotly-dash

I'm trying to run a python script for plotly dash, but when opening the script I got these issues. How to resolve them?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the dash, numpy and other libraries installed. Or just run pip install for Rachel library